# Oracle DB connection error with Python - cx_Oracle: cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am trying to use cx_Oracle (64bit python) to access my Oracle database. I followed the instruction [here](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows).

I installed `cx_Oracle 7.2.3` and downloaded `instantclient-basic-windows.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip` with `VC 2015-2019` (use the link provided in the page)

Actually, i have installed almost all versions of VC++

[image]

i added the Oracle Instant Client folder to my system environment variable, and I double checked it by typing 'PATH' in cmd.

However, when i run `cx_Oracle.connect('xxx')`, i still got an error saying,

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "The specified module could not be found". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help

What could be possible reason for the error? How to fix it?

Comment: Did you run Python in the command prompt in which you typed the PATH command? You can check the value of PATH in Python itself by examining the value of os.environ["PATH"]

Comment: yes, i also added my Oracle Instant Client folder path as the first element in os.environ["PATH"], but still got the same error.

Comment: Check the output from ``depends.exe`` to confirm that everything can be found. The error is stating that OCI.dll or one of its dependencies cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks, Anthony. But may i know which depends.exe you are referring to?

Comment: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: For future readers: Use the renamed, latest version of cx_Oracle since it doesn't need Oracle Client libraries, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) and you won't get DPI-1047 with the default install.  Note the driver got renamed to python-oracledb.  You can install with `pip` from https://pypi.org/project/oracledb/.

Answer (score 2):

This error mainly occurs because of instantclient version and cx_Oracle not compatible. Solution is to replace the instantclient with the required version mentioned in the error message (in your case 64-Bit).

**How to replace instantclient:**
Then if your problem continue, find the latest instantClient (Caution! version which your error refers not your Python/Windows version, in above case  64-bit) on [**Oracle Downloads**](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html), download and replace it with your current PATH on system variables or just replace new download with your current instantClient folder.

Also, checking on your VS redistributable version corresponding to your Oracle DB version is correct and installed as refereed in [**cx_oracle Docs**](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#troubleshooting) is proposed method, but in many of our cases it didn't caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Import cx_Oracle module and initialize it with the Oracle Instance Client location 64x like this:

```py
import cx_Oracle
cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"PATH_ORACLE_INSTANCE_64x")
```